# How to determine time remaining for a progress bar?

Tags: excel, vba, progress-bar

I have a VBA macro that runs through a minimum of 15,000 rows (records) which takes a while to complete.

I have a Progress Bar that displays which row is processing and a blue progress bar.

I would like to add how much time is remaining, how much time has passed and a notification that the process is complete.

Below is the entire module code.

```vb
Sub ZipCodeToSheet()
Dim MapSheet As Worksheet
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim code As String
Dim sh As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("DATA SHEET")
Set MapSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Zip Code Match")
ws.Activate
'Display Progress Bar
ufProgress.LabelProgress.Width = 0
ufProgress.Show
'----------
For i = 1 To ws.Range("J999999").End(xlUp).Row
'Periodically update progress bar
pctdone = i / ws.Range("J999999").End(xlUp).Row
With ufProgress
.LabelCaption.Caption = "Processing Row " & i & " of " & ws.Range("J999999").End(xlUp).Row
.LabelProgress.Width = pctdone * (.FrameProgress.Width)
End With
ufProgress.Repaint
DoEvents
'--------------------------------------
code = Trim(ws.Range("J1").Offset(i, 0).Text)
With MapSheet.Cells
On Error GoTo nextva:
r = .Find(What:=code, After:=MapSheet.Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Row
c = .Find(What:=code, After:=MapSheet.Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlFormulas, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Column - 1
End With
ws.Range(ws.Cells(i + 1, 1), ws.Cells(i + 1, 22)).Copy
newname = MapSheet.Range("A1").Cells(r, c).MergeArea.Cells(1, 1).Value
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(fuzzymatch(CStr(newname)))
ar = sh.Range("B999999").End(xlUp).Row + 1
sh.Range(sh.Cells(ar, 2), sh.Cells(ar, 23)).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
thosc:
Next
'Close the progress bar
If i = ws.Range("J999999").End(xlUp).Row Then Unload ufProgress
'----------
Exit Sub
nextva:
Resume thosc

End Sub


Function fuzzymatch(s As String) As String
Dim ab As Integer
Dim highest As Integer
Dim ss As String
highest = -1
For Each sh In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
ab = 0
If s = sh.Name Then
fuzzymatch = s
Exit Function
End If
For i = 1 To Len(s)
If InStr(sh.Name, (Mid(s, i, 1))) > 0 Then
ab = ab + 1
End If
Next
If ab > highest Then
highest = ab
ss = sh.Name
End If
Next

fuzzymatch = ss
End Function
```

Comment: How can you define the total time needed to complete? It's a bit tricky...

Comment: Which specific part of this are you having a problem with?  What did you try and what problems did you run into?  Your code does twice as many `Find()` calls as it needs - you might be better spending time making it run more efficiently...

Comment: You can't predict how long it will take to execute code. But I am almost sure that it is possible to write the code so execution will not last longer than 1 or 2 seconds

Comment: ...updating the progressbar for every row also makes it even slower.

Comment: Probably the best you can do is to take a timestamp at the beginning of each row process to determine the time taken for a single row, e.g. one row in one second for 15,000 rows is 15,000 seconds or 4 hours and 10 minutes. Then keep a running average of each row's processing time and you can project the amount of time remaining. It's not perfect by any means, but it's something.

Comment: Look at [**`GetTickCount()`**](https://bettersolutions.com/vba/macros/timing.htm) API to get time elapsed in milliseconds and estimate time elapsed vs work % completed and thus projected finish time.

Answer (score 0):

On your progress bar control (I took mine from http://spreadsheetpage.com/index.php/tip/C29/) add a private API call to `GetTickCount()` and a `tic` counter to keep when the process starts

```
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetTickCount Lib "kernel32.dll" () As Long
Private m_tic As Long
```

I have some reset code which sets the `tic` counter

```
Public Sub ResetProgress()
    PctDone = 0
    m_tic = GetTickCount()
End Sub
```

as well as functions for the elapsed time (in second) and estimated total time (in seconds)

```
Public Property Get ElapsedSeconds() As Single
    Dim toc As Long
    toc = GetTickCount()
    If toc >= m_tic Then
        ElapsedSeconds = (toc - m_tic) / 1000!
    Else
        ElapsedSeconds = 0
    End If
End Property

Public Property Get EstimatedTotalSeconds() As Single
    EstimatedTotalSeconds = 0
    If PctDone > 0 Then
        EstimatedTotalSeconds = ElapsedSeconds / PctDone
    End If
End Property
```

And then on the setter for the percent progress done (`PctDone`) I have code to display the % as well as the elapsed time / total time

```
Public Property Let PctDone(ByVal x As Single)
    Dim pct As String, tt As String, dt As Single
    pct_done = ClampMinMax(x, 0, 1)
    pct = Format(pct_done, "0.#%")
    dt = ElapsedSeconds
    If dt >= 0 Then
        tt = Format(ElapsedSeconds, "0.#") & "/" & Format(EstimatedTotalSeconds, "0.#") & " sec"
        Me.FrameProgress.Caption = pct & " (" & tt & ")"
    Else
        Me.FrameProgress.Caption = pct
    End If
    Me.LabelProgress.Width = pct_done * (Me.FrameProgress.Width - 10)
    DoEvents
End Property
```

and with some sample results:

[image: scr1]